# Smallest difference by more values

Tags: statistics

I am calculating a three different values by testing.
Example:
Wanted
A: 10
B: 10
C: 10

Calculated
A: 9
B: 12
C: 13

Difference between these values 
A%: -10
B%: +20
C%: +30

Calculated 2nd
A: 11
B: 8
C: 6

Difference between these values
A%: +10
B%: -20
C%: -40

How do I determine what calculation is closer to my wanted values?

Comment: I would use the sum of squared differences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares

Comment: @MattiP. how would you calculate this with these values?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the "distance" between two sets of values (as compared to only one-dimensional scalars), the standard approach is to calculate the sum of squared differences. So if you have vectors (or lists of values) $x$ and $y$, the sum of squared differences is calculated by
$$
L^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2
$$
where $x_i$ are the elements of the list $x$, and $y_i$ are the elements of $y$.

As a numerical example, let's set $x=(10, 10, 10)$ and $y=(9,12,13)$. Now the sum of squared differences is
$$
L^2 = (10-9)^2 + (10-12)^2 + (10-13)^3 = 1 + 4 + 9 = 14
$$
So remember that this is not the only way, but perhaps the most natural and popular one. Can you calculate these yourself now?